# stacked column highchart custom modifications

Tags: highcharts

I attached the below photo describe the challenge that I have
hide black color value change the black color to red and decrease the black color value from the total

```
here is the code URL

    https://jsfiddle.net/Anasddrx/gtyhrvp3/33/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SlRc.png)

Answer (score 0):

To set the red color for the `Stop series` and hide `dataLabels` use this config:

```
 {
    name: 'Stop',
    data: [5000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 2000],
        color: 'red',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
  },
```

To subtract Stop value from the stacking sum try this approach:

```
  formatter: function() {
            const stopSeries = this.axis.series.find(s => s.name === 'Stop');

    return this.total - stopSeries.processedYData[this.x] + " Pcs";
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pq7tdufk/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.color

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels